# Removing Uniqueness from an Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On one of my tables in SQL Server, In the Indexes folder I have a **Clustered Index** made from three columns of that table but there is also a `Unique` checkbox when I go to properties window on that index.
My question is with T-SQL commands how I tell it to drop the Uniqueness part and still keep the index? Is it even possible?

Comment: @Lashane I had seen that but that one is about dropping the whole index. I want to keep the index and judt drop the uniqness of it.

Comment: `Indexes created as the result of a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint cannot be deleted by using this method. Instead, the constraint must be deleted. To remove the constraint and corresponding index, use ALTER TABLE with the DROP CONSTRAINT clause in Transact-SQL.`

Comment: @Bohn You can't - `Clustered` indexes *must* be unique.  You will need to drop the index and make a new `NonClustered` one.

Comment: It's not true. Clustered index can be non-unique. It's used for semantical search, for very fast search in very unique cases. If the clustered index is not a unique index, SQL Server makes any duplicate keys unique by adding an internally generated value called a uniqueifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot alter index from unique to non-unique. You can set index to ignore duplicates.

Docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx

You can only recreate index with drop and create commands.

```
DROP INDEX IndexTest.ci_Test;
CREATE INDEX ci_Test ON IndexTest(Key);
```

But you should have clustered index on one column (for example on new autoincrement primary key). And you can force uniqueness with unique non-clustered index.